# Altering groupby and value_counts output for mapping to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a scenario where I am trying to filter a dataframe by a particular value, and count how many times another identifier is present. I'm then turning that into a dictionary and mapping back to the dataframe. The issue I am having is that the resulting dictionary cannot be mapped back to the dataframe because I'm introducing complexity to the dictionary (extra keys?), and I don't know how to avoid it.

I guess the simple question is: 'How can I use value_counts on my CELL_ID column', filter by another column called Grid_Type, and map the results back to all cells per CELL_ID?

**What I'm doing so far**

This works to count how many cells contain the CELL_ID, but does NOT allow me to filter by Grid_Type

```
df['CELL_ID'].value_counts()
z1 = z.to_dict()
df['CELL_CNT'] = df['CELL_ID'].map(z1)
```

The dictionary output from this simple example looks like:

```
7015988: 1, 7122961: 1, 6976792: 1
```

**My bad code**
This is what I've been working on so far - where I want to be able to return the count, filtered by the Grid_Type. Eg I want to be able to count the number of times I see "Spot" in/by each CELL_ID.

```
z = df[df.Grid_Type == 'Spot'].groupby('CELL_ID')['Grid_Type'].value_counts()
z1 = z.to_dict()
df['SPOT_CNT'] = df['CELL_ID'].map(z1)
```

It seems that in the example where I'm trying to filter that the dictionary is returning a more complex result that includes the Grid_Type. The thing is, I only want the counts mapped against the Cell_ID. Eg dictionary response:

```
(7133691, 'Spot'): 3, (7133692, 'Spot'): 3, (7133693, 'Spot'): 2
```

**Example Data**

```
+---------+-----------+
| CELL_ID | Grid_Type |
+---------+-----------+
|     001 | Spot      |
|     001 | Square    |
|     001 | Spot      |
|     001 | Square    |
|     001 | Square    |
|     002 | Spot      |
|     002 | Square    |
|     002 | Square    |
|     003 | Square    |
|     003 | Spot      |
|     003 | Spot      |
|     003 | Spot      |
+---------+-----------+
```

**Desired Outcome**

```
+---------+-----------+----------+
| CELL_ID | Grid_Type | SPOT_CNT |
+---------+-----------+----------+
|     001 | Spot      |        2 |
|     001 | Square    |        2 |
|     001 | Spot      |        2 |
|     001 | Square    |        2 |
|     001 | Square    |        2 |
|     002 | Spot      |        1 |
|     002 | Square    |        1 |
|     002 | Square    |        1 |
|     003 | Square    |        3 |
|     003 | Spot      |        3 |
|     003 | Spot      |        3 |
|     003 | Spot      |        3 |
+---------+-----------+----------+
```

Thanks for any help you might be able to offer/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = pd.read_csv('spot.txt', sep=r"[ ]{1,}", engine='python', dtype='object')

print(df)

    CELL_ID Grid_Type
0   001 Spot
1   001 Square
2   001 Spot
3   001 Square
4   001 Square
5   002 Spot
6   002 Square
7   002 Square
8   003 Square
9   003 Spot
10  003 Spot
11  003 Spot

df_gb = df['Grid_Type'].groupby([df['CELL_ID']]).value_counts()

print(df_gb)

    CELL_ID  Grid_Type
001      Square       3
         Spot         2
002      Square       2
         Spot         1
003      Spot         3
         Square       1
Name: Grid_Type, dtype: int64



df_gb_dict = df_gb.to_dict()

count_list = []

for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    for k, v in df_gb_dict.items():
        if k[0] == row['CELL_ID'] and k[1] == row['Grid_Type'] and row['Grid_Type'] == 'Spot':
            count_list.append([k[0], k[1], v])
        if k[0] == row['CELL_ID'] and k[1] == row['Grid_Type'] and row['Grid_Type'] == 'Square':
            count_list.append([k[0], k[1], df_gb_dict[(row['CELL_ID'], 'Spot')]])


new_df = pd.DataFrame(count_list, columns=['CELL_ID',  'Grid_Type', 'SPOT_CNT'])

new_df.sort_values(by='CELL_ID', inplace=True)

new_df.reset_index(drop=True)

print(new_df)

  CELL_ID Grid_Type  SPOT_CNT
0      001      Spot         2
1      001    Square         2
2      001      Spot         2
3      001    Square         2
4      001    Square         2
5      002      Spot         1
6      002    Square         1
7      002    Square         1
8      003    Square         3
9      003      Spot         3
10     003      Spot         3
11     003      Spot         3
```

Comment: Good answer, thanks. I'll be able to digest that and use in a vew places, I think. I did also find I was able to use `z = df[df.Grid_Type == 'Spot'].groupby('CELL_ID')['Grid_Type'].count()` to get a count. value_counts() was the wrong method to be using, I think.

Comment: I realized your question wanted only the spot count in the last column, even for the square rows, so I edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you have an answer, but I would approach this problem with [`transform()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html):

```
# set it up
df = pd.read_clipboard()
print(df)

    CELL_ID Grid_Type
0         1      Spot
1         1    Square
2         1      Spot
3         1    Square
4         1    Square
5         2      Spot
6         2    Square
7         2    Square
8         3    Square
9         3      Spot
10        3      Spot
11        3      Spot
```

```
df['SPOT_CNT'] = df.groupby('CELL_ID')['Grid_Type'].transform(lambda x: sum(x == 'Spot'))
print(df)

    CELL_ID Grid_Type  SPOT_CNT
0         1      Spot         2
1         1    Square         2
2         1      Spot         2
3         1    Square         2
4         1    Square         2
5         2      Spot         1
6         2    Square         1
7         2    Square         1
8         3    Square         3
9         3      Spot         3
10        3      Spot         3
11        3      Spot         3
```

Inside the `lambda` function:
 - it returns bool if value(`x`) == `'Spot'`
 - for each group, `sum()` adds up the `True` bools
Lastly [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html),as per docs, behaves like so:

```
DataFrame.transform(self, func, axis=0, *args, **kwargs) → 'DataFrame'[source]
     "Call func on self producing a DataFrame with transformed values."  
     "Produced DataFrame will have same axis length as self." <----
...
```

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thanks. Does this create a second data frame?

Comment: In a technical sense yes, but we are assigning it to original `df` as column `'SPOT_CNT'`